# Cannot find module 'x' or its corresponding type declarations when running Jest Github Actions

Tags: typescript, jestjs, github-actions, ts-jest, tsconfig-paths

When I run my Jest test suite locally, the tests have no problem finding my imported modules and tests complete successfully. However, on Github Actions. The module seems not able to be found, and tests fail due to this.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my config that may be causing this?

**Error message:**

```
src/ui/components/Icon.tsx:3:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/../public/icons/fa-bars-light.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import Svgs1 from "@/../public/icons/fa-bars-light.svg";
```

**jest.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    ".(ts|tsx)": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\.svg$": "jest-transformer-svg" // required to enable svg imports during test runs
  },
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', 'public']
};
```

**tsconfig.js (relevant keys)**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    .../
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "public/icons/*.svg"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Relevant directory structure**

```
public
   - icons
src
  - ui
    - components
      - Icon.tsx
tsconfig.json
jest.config.js
```

**Github Action Workflow**

```
name: Node.js CI
run-name: "Run Unit Tests"
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '18.17.1'
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm i
    - run: npm test
```

Relevant package.json packages:

```
{
  ...,
  "jest-transformer-svg": "^2.0.2",
  "jest": "^29.7.0",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
  "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
}
```

Comment: try to clone that repo from scratch to your local machine then npm i and npm test and let's see what happen.

Comment: maybe that may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949989/jest-cannot-find-module-but-only-when-running-on-github-actions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried both. Cloning the repo also caused the actions to fail locally again, however, after creating a new transformer as per the Jest Docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation) it worked again. But, when I pushed to Github the build had the same result. Have also tried clearing the GH cache but has made no difference.